# Can I assign a member function to a local variable in a python class

Tags: python

I have a class;

```
class Foo:
    bar = fooFunc

    def fooFunc():
        return True
```

The linter complains:  fooFunc is not defined. What could I be missing. Thanks

Comment: I've only ever used Python 3 so I could be wrong but shouldn't it be "Foo.fooFunc"?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you did `bar = foo` followed by `foo = bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems logical: the code gets executed sequentially. If you want to use `fooFunc`, you have to define it first! Simply try

```py
class Foo:
  def fooFunc():
    pass
  bar = fooFunc
```

Also, note that a function defined in a class by default will be a method, so it should accept at least `self`. If you just want to put it there for namespacing reasons, you should make it a `staticmethod` instead.

Comment: Thank you @BlackBeans. This fixed it. Coming from the Javascript land, I'm used to hoisting where it doesn't matter whether the function is defined before or after